# Reload Table on appWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I have been trying to reload a table any time the user reenters my iphone app. All of the information for the table is correct and proper. The table is entering the proper data sources and delegates and the values I am printing out are what I want, but visually the table will not reload visually. My calls are in the appWillEnterForeground and the call is made to viewWillLoad.

Comment: Code in this case would not help because it is literally 
MealPlan *resetObj = [[MealPlan alloc]init];
[resetObj viewDidLoad];

Comment: It would help, since that code looks wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be firing viewDidLoad as you describe in the comment above. viewDidLoad is a special method that the CocoaTouch framework calls at the appropriate times. It should not be called by your code directly.

Instead, you can use Notifications to accomplish the same thing. Here's the correct way to do what you're asking for:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Fire a notification to let all views know that our app entered foreground.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnteredForeground" 
                                                        object:nil];
}
```

Handle the notification in your specific ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(enteredForeground:) 
                                                name:@"EnteredForeground" 
                                              object:nil];
}

// Handle the notification in your ViewController:

- (void)enteredForeground:(id)object {
    // Reload the tableview
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: That was awesome thank you so much for that. I had been banging my head against the wall for like an hour cause I had all the correct information being called but no visual proof. So thank you good sir.

Comment: you can observe UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just observe UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification instead of posting your own notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.tableView selector:@selector(reloadData) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```